# rCharts: Highcharts - how to flip coordinates for bar chart?

Tags: highcharts, rcharts

I was expecting a normal bar chart. However, the X axis is where the Y axis should be:

**I think it is so difficult to find the righ documentation, but thanks to @ramnathv for these wrapper**

[image]

RCode:

```
h1 <- hPlot(x = "fuente", y = "sessions", data = usertypexfuente2, type = c("bar"))

h1$tooltip(formatter="#!function () {
  return 'Sesiones '  +
    ': <b>' + this.y + '</b>' +  ' (' + this.x + ')' ;
}!#")


h1
```

*I can add the data, if needed*

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

There is not a good documentation on the RCharts package. Since It is a wrapper. All documentation needed, should be looked up in the official page for the JS libraries, in this case "highcharts".

This is the page for the colum chart (from my expirience it should be called bar chart (ggplot2 user), therefore the mess in my head):

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

**You should click on "View Options" and copy the Type part**

Just need to change the type of the graph to "column":

RCode:

```
h1 <- hPlot(x = "fuente", y = "sessions", data = usertypexfuente2, type = c("column"))

h1$tooltip(formatter="#!function () {
  return 'Sesiones '  +
    ': <b>' + this.y + '</b>' +  ' (' + this.x + ')' ;
}!#")


h1
```